# I am multiplying two complex numbers whose imaginary parts are both zero, I was expecting the result to be only real but I get an imaginary part

Tags: c, complex-numbers

I am multiplying the reciprocal of the determinant of a matrix by the transposed cofactor matrix to get the inverse matrix. Some of the values in the transposed cofactor matrix will have an imaginary value not equaled to or very close to zero.
I am trying to replicate code originally written in matlab, so there are exact target values I am trying to achieve, any differences in the values propagate themselves throughout the rest of the calculations resulting in very different final values. Is it possible to do? Or will there always very differences between the two codes calculations?

(I have revised my code to show the small values)This the function and the output.

```
 void MatrixScalarMultiply(int r, int c, double complex x, double complex mat[r][c], 
                          double complex result[r][c]){
    
    for (int R=0; R<r; R++){
        for (int C=0; C<c; C++){
            printf("%.16g%+.16gi times %.16g%+.16gi\n", creal(x), cimag(x), creal(mat[R][C]), cimag(mat[R][C]));
            result[R][C] = x * mat[R][C];
            printf("result[%d][%d]:%.16g%+.16gi\n", R, C, creal(result[R][C]), cimag(result[R][C]));
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
1122579414.726753+0i times 0.0004943535237422733-2.632898458153072e-21i
result[0][0]:554951.0893507092-2.955637610188447e-12i
```

Comment: Use `"%.17g"` instead of `"%f"` to get more info on small values.  We do not yet fully  know the imaginary parts are zero.  The `-` in `-0.0000000000000000` is telling that the value is _not_ +0.0.

Comment: The example output result is wrong.  I get `1122579414.7267532+0j` (tested with Python).  Better to provide a [mcve] that has a main that calls the function so we can reproduce the exact result.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right, using "%.16g" I can see that the imaginary part of the second number is actually a very small number. Is there a way I can round those off to zero?

Comment: @JesusSoto: Usually it is a mistake to attempt to “correct” errors in floating-point arithmetic by “rounding” to something. Floating-point arithmetic is designed to approximate real-number arithmetic, and the errors that the mathematics and logic dictate have to be accepted with that. The floating-point arithmetic rules have been designed to limit those errors to the extent the formats and goals permit, but they still must occur. Attempting to “correct” errors typically reduces small frequent errors at the cost of creating large rare errors.

Comment: @JesusSoto: If you know that a certain calculation necessarily yields a pure real result when performed with real-number arithmetic, then simply print only the real part of the floating-point result. But that suggests some of the complex arithmetic may have been unnecessary in the first place. For more advice, you need to detail the calculations you are doing.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: The example output is not wrong. `x` and/or `mat[R][C]` have very small imaginary parts that were converted to “0.0000000000000000” in accordance with the specification for the `%.16f` conversion specification. The complex multiplication correctly produced a non-zero imaginary part which was converted to “0.0000000000029556”also in accordance with the specification for the `%.16f` conversion specification.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: It was entirely obvious, as this is well-known behavior, and well-known correct behavior is much more likely than that the output was incorrect.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Giving an answer because we have sufficient data is practical. Insisting upon conformance to a guideline when it is unnecessary because we already have the answer is pedantic.

Comment: @EricPostpischilc when I posted the original comment there was no answer and since then the question was edited to provide additional detail

Answer (score 0):

> I am multiplying two complex numbers whose imaginary parts are both zero,

As OP found out by using exponential notation, the imaginary parts were not both zero.

> ... any differences in the values propagate themselves throughout the rest of the calculations resulting in very different final values. Is it possible to do?

Yes, it is possible, yet often not likely to have a floating-point calculation on 2 platforms result in the same *exact* result.  A more reasonable approach is to tolerate a small difference.  What constitutes a small difference depends on the calculation, which is not yet shown.

> Or will there always very differences between the two codes calculations?

No, there will not always differ.  Again, what constitutes a small difference depends on the calculation, which is not yet shown.

> ... can see that the imaginary part of the second number is actually a very small number. Is there a way I can round those off to zero?

Yes, code could round as it did using the `"%+.16f"` format in an earlier version of the question.  That rounded the display value and not `mat[R][C]`.

Instead of attempting to "round those off to zero", consider analyzing code and determine what tolerance is possible.  A simply, though not so mathematical sound, approach adjusts the various input real and imaginary arguments 1 [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (ULP), both up and down with `nextafter()` and noticing the range of outputs.

Alternatively, the algorithm and true code should be posted in a separate question to help analyze why the imaginary part does not meet OP's expectations.